# Index and Match Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a vacation tracker in Excel. The first sheet pulls the data from SharePoint which has Start Date, End Date and a Date Difference calculation.

Sheet1

```
A2=12/16/2015
B2=12/20/2015
C2=5
```

The second sheet is the visualization of the data. It starts with cell B1 and goes out for 90 days. Is is a word representation of the date. Here is the formula I'm using `=UPPER(TEXT(B2,"DDD"))`

Sheet2

```
B1=WED
C1=THU
D1=FRI
E1=SAT
F1=SUN
```

The next row always `B2` has a formula which is always today's date. From there I add one date to increment the dates out to 90 days. `B2=Today()` and the other cells `=B2+1` and so forth

```
B2=16
C2=17
D2=18
E2=19
F2=20
```

The problem I'm running to is that our boss can have 3 calendar entries consisting of different dates. So when I perform a SharePoint pull I have 3 different rows of vacation dates. I'm experimenting with an Index and Match example, however the data match it is placed in a new row. How do I place the data on the same row?

Comment: Please show us some code you already have, and where it has errors or where it needs to be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this has much to do with VBA. Seems enough detail of final design but rather light on the data gathering process. However *when I perform a SharePoint pull I have 3 different rows of vacation dates* hints at a use for Subtotal. Three rows may be 'converted' into one:

[image: SO34310986 example]

where the unshaded part (some cells with `X`s) is assumed to be a representation of the current SharePoint data extract. Subtotal is able to add the rows shown lightly filled, which might then be used to `=VLOOKUP("Boss"&" Count",A:F,n,0)` where `n` represent the choice of column label.

Comment: You're correct it was not so much a VBA as it is using SUMIFS along with a Pivot table. I found another website that provided a pretty close example that I'm using. Thanks for the reply I will use it if needed